# Error on post Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an issue with a Contact Form. I'm just trying to make a simple post with express.

I have the following code:

**views/contacto.jade**

```
  extends layout-inside
  block content
  .main-container
  form(action='contacto', name='contacto', id='contacto', method='post')
  section.cover.fullscreen.image-bg.overlay
  .background-image-holder
  img.background-image(alt='image', src='/images/bg-6.jpg')
  |                 
  .container.v-align-transform
  .row
  .col-sm-6.col-sm-offset-3
  .feature.bordered.text-center
  h4.uppercase Contacto
  |                                 
  form.text-left
  input(type='text', name='name', placeholder='Nombre')
  |                                     
  input(type='text', name='email', placeholder='Email')
  |                                     
  input(type='text', name="telefono", placeholder='Teléfono')
  |                                     
  textarea(name="mensaje",  placeholder='mensaje')
  |                                     
  input(type='submit', value='Enviar')
  |
```

**routes/index.js**

```
  router.get('/contacto', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('contacto', { title: 'Contacto'});
  });
```

And when I do the post in the form I got this error:

```
  Error: Not Found
  at /Users/dev/node/website/app.js:33:13
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/dev/node/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/Users/dev/node/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /Users/dev/node/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/Users/dev/node/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/Users/dev/node/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at /Users/dev/node/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
  at next (/Users/dev/node/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
  at Function.handle (/Users/dev/node/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
  at router (/Users/dev/node/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening? It appears that the file is not there.

Thanks

Comment: `router.get` is for a GET request, if it's a POST request you're listening for, it should be `router.post`, or even `router.all` for all types ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're distinct HTTP verbs, `GET` isn't same as `POST`, when doing a `GET /contactos` you render back a view, that's ok. When clicking on submit you will attempt to perform a `POST request`.

You may add something like this to handle the form submit via POST:

```
 router.post('/contacto', function(req, res, next) {
  var formData = request.body;
  // Do stuff
  return response.end(201);
 });
```

For your API, you should prefix routes with /api, for example: `/api/contacts`. Also, you should code it all in english.

### Edit. Express 4 configs

You should use a `Router` object to setup your routes as explained in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106640/express-router-vs-app-get/31107198#31107198).

Comment: Thanks! That work perfect for me. I was writing the post in app.post instead of router.post  Do yo know the difference? :)

Comment: As you are configuring Express with its routher as Express 4 settings, you somehow gotta do router.post.