# Exception while using a router object in a typescript class in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, routes

I have a nodejs service in typescript. I'm trying to set a separate routing layer in the application.

I have a app.js file where in

```
let IndividualRoute= require('./routing/IndividualRoute');
app.use('/users', IndividualRoute);
```

I have create a IndividualRoute.ts file where im trying to use router object like below

```
import express = require('express');
import individualValidation from '../users/IndividualValidation';
let router = express.Router();

class IndividualRoute {
         router.get('/individualList', individualValidation.list);
}

export = IndividualRoute;
```

When i try to do the above, i get the below exception

[image]

**I tried the below things**

```
router.get('/individualList', (request, response) => {
        response.send('Hello world!');
});
```

But i get the same issue. Also if i remove the class and have a simple file without class then i don't get this exception.

Basically what im trying to do is, if the route matches it should hit the respective function in the IndividualValidation file like in below case

```
router.get('/individualList', individualValidation.list);
```

If the route is users/individualList it should hit individualValidation.list function with the request data. Basically im trying to do what is marked as answer in the below link

[express.Router() vs. app.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106640/express-router-vs-app-get?rq=1)

Any suggestion what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing a class. Inside a class, put the constructor and methods.  You can't write code directly here. The line you wrote needs to be in the constructor or in a method.

```
class IndividualRoute {
      constructor(){
         router.get('/individualList', individualValidation.list);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `IndividualRoute.ts`, please make the following changes:

```js
import { Router } from 'express';
import individualValidation from '../users/IndividualValidation';
let router = Router();

router.get('/individualList', individualValidation.list);

export default router;
```

Also, if using typescript, why you have app.js? I'll suggest using typescript for that file also. One more suggestion would be to have index.ts in your `routing` folder with code:

```js
import { Router } from express;
import IndividualRoute from "./IndividualRoute";

let router = Router();
router.use("/users", IndividualRoute); // set this for each individual route
/*
 * e.g.
 * router.use("/auth", auth);
*/

export default router;
```

So in your `app.ts`, all you have to do is:

```js
import * as express from "express";
import routes from "./routing";

let app = express();
app.use(routes);

// other code
```

I hope you find this helpful!

Comment: i get the below error after making changes to the app.ts
Waiting for the debuError: Cannot find module './routing'

Comment: so to be clear, in your root folder, you have file app.ts, folder routing and in folder routing, you have file index.ts?